# stanfordnlp - Training space separated words as a single token to Stanford NER model generation

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have read the detailed description given here- http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a on training the model based on the labelled input file according to the .prop file. But the article says-

```
You should make sure each line consists of solely content fields and tab characters. Spaces don't work. Extra tabs will cause problems.
```

My text corpus has some space separated words which are all combinedly form a token instead of single word. For instance, "Wright State University" is a single token though Wright, State and University are entities individually. I would like to generate the model with the above token as a single one. The article says that the input file to generate the model should be given as a tab separated words with first column being the token and the second column the label. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically NER training data is in the form of natural language sentences where each token has an NER tag.  You might have 10,000 sentences or more.

For instance: "He attended Wright State University."

should be represented as:

```
He   O
attended   O
Wright   SCHOOL
State    SCHOOL
University   SCHOOL
.   O
```

If don't have sentences, and you simply have a list of strings that should be tagged a certain way, it makes more sense to use RegexNER.

You can find a thorough description of how to use RegexNER here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html